# Slack integrations

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am building a slack app whereby I am using incoming-webhook scope. While authorising, post to channel option comes only for the already created channels, I don't get any create a new channel and post like option.

Update:

Attached screenshots

[image: This is my app]

[image: Some other app. The create new channel option is missing in mine]

Comment: Please post your code for better understanding.

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

updated: It looks like you just want a link to create a new channel correct? If that's the case, that is something the Slack Dev team have to add.

On your end, incoming webhooks does not allow automated new channel creation.